# geoNear with MongoDB, minDistance not implemented in aggregation?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm having trouble using the **minDistance** option with **$geoNear** inside the **MongoDB aggregation** framework. I know this works with $near, *but I need to use aggregate to include the distanceField and some other derived values in the result set*

Node version: 0.12.0

MongoDB version: 2.6.10

Example:

```
db.myCollection.aggregate([
    { $geoNear: {
        'near': [
          lng,
          lat
        ],
        'spherical': true,
        'distanceField': 'dis',
        'distanceMultiplier': distMult,
        'maxDistance': maxDis, // works
        // 'minDistance': minDis, // Does not work
      }
    },
    ...

])
```

Other notes:

My work around uses a skip value (where the skip value produces the same result as minDistance), but the performance is terrible. Open to any suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered/tried including both `$near` (which supports `$minDistance`) and `$geoNear` (which supports `distanceField`) in your pipeline?

Comment: Disregard this - `$near` is not available either in `$match` step in the pipeline, nor within query passed to `$geoNear` (`query` option). See this: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-14421 . I'm afraid you might be out of luck here.